# Can I map gpu drivers of host machine (windows) inside docker container?

Tags: windows, docker, nvidia-docker

I am trying to execute a codebase (detect and track by facebook) inside the docker container that requires GPU access. My docker image is linux based with CUDA toolkit installed however I cannot see any GPU devices in proc filesystem.

The host machine is windows with CUDA 9 toolkit and drivers installed.
When I try to execute the code it says:

```
CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

On searching, I realized, I can leverage nvidia-docker plugin to map the host nvidia drivers to container OS but by the looks of it, I couldn't find any support for windows.

Is there any other way around to execute the codebase inside docker container on my windows OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible on any Windows OS.

https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#is-microsoft-windows-supported